# Can I hide the badges on the tabs of editor?

Tags: visual-studio-code

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hzo5A.png)
Can this badge of file type be hiden?

I've looked up all the "tab" in the "workbench.editor.*" setting.